# Defining and using a Global "custom" analyzer in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

We have created our own custom analyzer definition based on our application-wide needs and that is quite different from available analyzers in ElasticSearch like standard or classical analyzers.

We have around 30 indices and i want to use this custom analyzer for all these indices. As much as I know and have searched, it seems that i need to include the analyzer definition in all the index definitions which seems like gross duplication of information.

Is it possible that I can define a custom analyzer once (possibly, without having to associate it's definition with any index), and then use this custom analyzer for several indices without having to redefine analyzer definition within each index definition?

Comment: Have you looked at index templates? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/indices-templates.html

Comment: Yes Ian, templates look promising. However, having to name indices in a particular way to have templates applied, that's something I would prefer to stay away from, at least for my simplistic scenario. Thanks anyways for pointing this out.

Comment: Ian, I think I misunderstood index templates. I understand now that setting up a match pattern for an index template just makes that template (and included analyzer definitions) "available to be used" for indices based on the pattern, and do NOT automatically "apply" them to the matching indices. This is exactly what I needed, thanks for your reply. If you had provided this as a reply and not as a comment, I would have marked this as the correct answer.